# How to get the IP address or the computer name of a machine from a network?

Tags: remote

How to get the IP address or the computer name of a machine from a network? I need my computer IP address or name to access it remotely from my phone, the computer turn on, but the screen is gone, so i can access it remotely but i need the IP address or the machine name to access it. There is a way to get one of these info??

My phone can execute UNIX prompt commands and i have nmap installed, but I don't know if it can help me!

Comment: If you have access to the router many of them will have a DCHP client list that will give you both the name & IP address.

Comment: I haven't a router here, just my phone hotspot connected to the computer